# yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed in this context (Python Black Box Testing help)

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, black-box-testing

I am trying to run use PBBT to call in input of a .yaml file which will then run the .py file. But I keep getting the following error "yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: expected a sequence of test records in "input12sys.yaml",line 3 column 3" (edit). I will attach the actual python bit for both the input file and the .yaml. So everyone can see what I might be/am doing wrong.

Any help getting this working properly would be greatly apprecaited as I am a novice at this whole pbbt thing.
Here is the .py file we want to have ran with the .yaml for pbbt (Daniel_Rogers_HW2.py is the file name)

```
import sys
# create a list
list2 = [4, 5, 1, 3, 7, 2, 5]
SumList = sum(list2)
print ("Dear Daniel")
print (*list2 , sep = " + ", end ='')
print (" =" , SumList)
```

Here is the .yaml file (edited)

```
output: output12sys.yaml
tests:
   py: Daniel_Rogers_HW2.py
   except: ValueError
```

And here is the error that I am getting when running pbbt input12sys.yaml -T
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your YAML file starts with:

```
import yaml

output:
```

And you cannot have a non-quoted multi-line scalar (`import yaml\n\noutput`) as a key for mapping. You probably just want to delete the `import yaml` line and if not you need to apply quotes:

```
"import yaml

output": output12sys.yaml
```

Assuming that `import yaml` is erroneous, you probably want to review your `pbbt` documentation, as the value for `tests` should be a list judging from https://bitbucket.org/prometheus/pbbt/src/default/. I.e. look like

```
output: output12sys.yaml
tests:
-  py: Daniel_Rogers_HW2.py    # note the list item indicator at the start of the line
   except: ValueError
```

Comment: Anthon,

I made the change as you recommended and now I am getting "yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed in this context in 'input12sys.yaml", line 5, column 6". I am confused because there is no acutal line 5?

`
output: output12sys.yaml
tests: 
  except: ValueError
  py: Daniel_Rogers_HW2.py
`
Is there a proper way to essentially end the file?

Comment: Not sure how your file looks like after the edit. Are you editing the file on Unix/Linux and running the software on windows?

Comment: its on windows. I will edit the original post to show how it is looking now and the current error for a line that does not exist so you can see that.

Comment: I updated my answer, you should probably re-consult your pbbt documentation, as this has no longer anything to do with YAML.